# How to run shell script or command after undeploying WAR from tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, war, undeploy

I have some symbolic links into my webapplication /WEB-INF folder that i want to get removed automatically everytime before my WAR has been undeployed. Is there any easy way to do that in Maven? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the `exec` goal of th [Exec Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html):

> A Plugin for executing external programs.